# js canvas - Compute text width with specific text-weight

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, html5-canvas

I'm currently using the following code to calculate text width:

```
function measureWordSize(word, font) {
    var canvas = measureWordSize.canvas || (measureWordSize.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(word);
    return metrics.width;
}
```

Which works fine, but the `font` property has to be a string formatted like so: `[italic] [bold] <font-size> <font-family>`.

I want to calculate the text's width with a certain `text-weight`, and setting font to `700px <font-size> <font-family>` doesn't work. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) doesn't say anything about a numeric `text-weight`.

How do I calculate text width for an element with a numeric `text-weight`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`context.font` accepts the same format as CSS [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font) shorthand property.

<sub>Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)</sub>

> /* size | family */
>   font: 2em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
>
> /* style | size | family */
>   font: italic 2em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
>
> /* style | variant | weight | size/line-height | family */
>   font: italic small-caps bolder 16px/3 cursive;
>
> /* style | variant | weight | stretch | size/line-height | family */
>   font: italic small-caps bolder condensed 16px/3 cursive;

So you can also set the [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Common_weight_name_mapping) as numeric scale, just like with CSS:

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const str = "I'm bold";
// set the font as numeric-font-weight | font-size | font-name
ctx.font = '700 16px sans-serif';
console.log('bold:', ctx.measureText(str).width);

ctx.fillText(str, 0, 20)
// reset to normal font-weight
ctx.font = '400 16px sans-serif';
console.log('medium:', ctx.measureText(str).width);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```